# Is the NSData a substring of the another NSData?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsdata

I have two `NSData` objects

```
NSData *toScan = /* initialized somehow with "Hello, this world." */;
NSData *toMatch = /* initialized somehow with "this" */;
```

What is the best way to know the `toMatch` bytes are the subset of `toScan` bytes?
I use C-functions for this purposes at this point: something like this

```
strstr([[toScan identifier] bytes], [[toMatch identifier] bytes]);
// returned bytes are null-terminated
```

but I think there is not the best way to use C-functions in object-oriented environment...

Comment: Your strstr will only work if the string toMatch is found in toScan. But what if toMatch is "cdb" instead? It's still a subset, but strstr won't catch that. Or will that not happen? Also: is space efficiency more important than computational efficiency? Will the bytes always be in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Snow Leopard and iOS 4.0, NSData has `-rangeOfData:options:range:` which should do what you want.

It's also pretty darn fast.

Answer (score 0):

In a different question, I wrote an answer containing an `NSData` category with a `rangeOfData:` method:

[Elegant Algorithm for Parsing Data Stream Into Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458960/elegant-algorithm-for-parsing-data-stream-into-record/2459015#2459015)

That'll do what you're looking for.